# What is the best way to perform a left/right outer join in LINQ and Entity Framework (method)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I did a lot of searching on this and didn't really find what I was looking for.  I like adding extension methods, so how would you do this with an extension method?

Answer (score 3):

Write some extension methods that make it nice and easy:

```
public class JoinResult<TL, TR>
{
    public TL Left { get; set; }
    public TR Right { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<JoinResult<TL, TR>> LeftJoin<TL, TR, TKey>(this IQueryable<TL> left, IQueryable<TR> right, Expression<Func<TL, TKey>> leftKeySelector, Expression<Func<TR, TKey>> rightKeySelector)
{
    return left
        .GroupJoin(right, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (l, rightGroup) => new { l, rightGroup = rightGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(z => z.rightGroup.Select(r => new JoinResult<TL, TR> { Left = z.l, Right = r }));
}

public static IQueryable<JoinResult<TL, TR>> RightJoin<TL, TR, TKey>(this IQueryable<TL> left, IQueryable<TR> right, Expression<Func<TL, TKey>> leftKeySelector, Expression<Func<TR, TKey>> rightKeySelector)
{
    return right
        .GroupJoin(left, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (r, leftGroup) => new { leftGroup = leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(), r })
        .SelectMany(z => z.leftGroup.Select(l => new JoinResult<TL, TR> { Left = l, Right = z.r }));
}
```